# How to execute svn command along with grep on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, svn, grep

Trying to execute svn command on windows machine and capture the output for the same.

Code:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "svn log -l1 https://repo/path/trunk | grep ^r | awk '{print \$3}'"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I do understand that `'grep'` is not windows utility.
Getting error as "grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Is it only limited to execute on Linux?
Can we execute the same on Windows?
Is my code right?

Comment: To have `grep` on a Windows computer, you can use [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). You could also consider using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

Comment: Grep is a GNU program and is by default available on Linux. But there are also Windows versions available e.g. here https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/ Alternatively you can install the [Chocolatey Package Manager](https://chocolatey.org/) and install grep via `choco install grep`. Another way is to install WSL on Windows (by Microsoft) + an Linux image like Ubuntu. Then you have a shell that access your regular NTFS file-system but runs Linux.

Comment: This commands prompt for password. How to automate this password entry ?

Comment: Please limit to one question per question. It should be easy to find how to use public-key authentication for Subversion as that's a very frequently asked question.

Answer (score 0):

For windows your command will look something like the following
`svn log -l1 https://repo/path/trunk | find "string_to_find"`

You need to use the find utility in windows to get the same effect as grep.

```
svn --version | find "ra"
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn log --search FOO` instead of grep-ing the command's output.

Comment: My copy of `svn` doesn't have this option, and neither does http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

Comment: It does exist in the 1.8 draft: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search ... but it seems to extract the entire log message anyway, which is already specified by the `-l 1`.

Comment: @tripleee upgrade your Subversion client anyway. You are using a *very* outdated version. Current version is 1.14.

Comment: I stopped using Subversion some five? Eight? Ten? years ago; I just happened to need it for the first time in two years earlier today, and was lucky to find a computer where I still had it installed.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` and `awk` are certainly available for Windows as well, but there is really no need to install them -- the code is easy to replace with native Python.

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(["svn", "log", "-l1", "https://repo/path/trunk"],
    capture_output=True, text=True)
for line in p.stdout.splitlines():
    # grep ^r
    if line.startswith('r'):
        # awk '{ print $3 }'
        print(line.split()[2])
```

Because we don't need a pipeline, and just run a single static command, we can avoid `shell=True`.

Because we don't want to do the necessary plumbing (which you forgot anyway) for `Popen()`, we prefer `subprocess.run()`. With `capture_output=True` we conveniently get its output in the resulting object's `stdout` atrribute; because we expect text output, we pass `text=True` (in older Python versions you might need to switch to the old, slightly misleading synonym `universal_newlines=True`).

I guess the intent is to search for the committer in each revision's output, but this will incorrectly grab the third token on any line which starts with an `r` (so if you have a commit message like "refactored to use Python native code" the code will extract `use` from that).  A better approach altogether is to request machine-readable output from `svn` and parse that (but it's unfortunately rather clunky XML, so there's another not entirely trivial rabbithole for you).  Perhaps as middle ground implement a more specific pattern for finding those lines -- maybe look for a specific number of fields, and static strings where you know where to expect them.

```py
    if line.startswith('r'):
        fields = line.split()
        if len(fields) == 13 and fields[1] == '|' and fields[3] == '|':
            print(fields[2])
```

You could also craft a regular expression to look for a date stamp in the third `|`-separated field, and the number of changed lines in the fourth.

For the record, a complete commit message from Subversion looks like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r16110 | tripleee | 2020-10-09 10:41:13 +0300 (Fri, 09 Oct 2020) | 4 lines

refactored to use native Python instead of grep + awk
(which is a useless use of grep anyway; see http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)
```

Comment: Do I really need to write Python code for something that simple?

Comment: If you're on Windows, nothing is simple. Installing (not necessarily completely compatible and/or free) Windows ports of general Unix tools is often necessary, but one more distraction, and then what are you doing on that sordid excuse of a platform if you really want to be on Unix? Pro: portability. Con: It would not have to be portable to Windows if you weren't on Windows. But all things counted, this is not hard code to write, understand, or maintain; and keeping most of the logic in Python is often more elegant and robust. (Also, will your future maintainer understand Awk?)

Comment: Also, pay attention to the multiple bug fixes here (one functional, one merely efficiency/elegance). If you can't write proper Awk but can write proper Python, the choice should be easy; and if you can't, probably concentrate on getting one of them right. So no, you don't have to write it in Python; but I'm convinced it's the better choice for most people with this particular problem.

Comment: Windows has PowerShell and it is available on Linux, too.

Comment: The one time I needed a PowerShell command, its syntax changed drastically between versions. But yeah, you could make a script which requires different external dependencies if you thought external dependencies are a good idea. Again, I'd recommend that you keep as much as possible of your code in a single language, and learn that language well.